# Ember.js: How to share package JSON file dependency to child engines and addons

Tags: javascript, html, npm, ember.js, package.json

Basically I need to know how Ember Js can share parent app package.json file dependency(xyz:3.0.0) to child engine and addons without being used again in child engine and addon package.json file. So that I can reduce the size of the application.

As of now in our application we installing common package dependency in all our child engines and addons even though we used in parent app its increases application size.

Here is my clear example of my project scenario.

parentApp(xxx):
Which has package.json file containes few dependency like ex: vendor-package1:10.0.0, vendor-package2:4.0.0, Child Engine1(yyy), Child Engine2(zzz)

Child Engine1(yyy)
Which has package.json file containes few dependency like ex: vendor-package1:10.0.0, vendor-package2:4.0.0

Child Engine2(zzz)
Which has package.json file containes few dependency like ex: vendor-package1:10.0.0, vendor-package2:4.0.0

So if you notice parent app and child engines has same dependency(vendor-package1:10.0.0, vendor-package2:4.0.0) which I need to do npm install for all three app. I'm adding (vendor-package:10.0.0, vendor-package2:4.0.0) to all my child engines because it should available to my engines.

Because of this my dist folder has (vendor-package1:10.0.0, vendor-package2:4.0.0) to all my parentApp and engines, which increase in size.

If I add(vendor-package1:10.0.0, vendor-package2:4.0.0) only to my parentApp(xxx) then my child engines cannot access those component inside vendor-package1 and vendor-package2.

Please suggest some solution where I don't want to add dependency to all my apps.

Comment: I'm surprised that the parent apps final size is increased by this, generally only one version of a package is included in the final app (which can sometimes cause bugs). Can you share some more details that may help me understand why this isn't working?

Comment: @jrjohnson I edited my description above with example. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

I've setup a demo ember 3.12 app at https://github.com/bartocc/so-58343095.

This app depends on [ember-concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/introduction/) and also has an in-repo addon `core` that depends on `ember-concurrency`.

I've also added `ember-cli-bundlesize` to help analyse the bundle size of the built app.

Here are the results of `ember bundlesize:test` before and after adding the in-repo addon.

#### Before

```sh
$ git checkout 6c5dfc7
$ ember bundlesize:test
ok 1 - app:javascript: 165.89KB <= 500KB (gzip)
ok 2 - app:css: 40B <= 50KB (gzip)
```

### After

```sh
$ git checkout 9c9c9a9
$ ember bundlesize:test
ok 1 - app:javascript: 165.89KB <= 500KB (gzip)
ok 2 - app:css: 40B <= 50KB (gzip)
Bundlesize check was successful. Good job!
```

As you can see, the bundlesize does not change.

---

The same goes for an in-repo engine:

### With in-repo engine depending on `ember-concurrency`

```sh
$ git checkout 2662b63
$ ember bundlesize:test
ok 1 - app:javascript: 170.08KB <= 500KB (gzip)
ok 2 - app:css: 40B <= 50KB (gzip)
Bundlesize check was successful. Good job!
```

The small difference you see between 165.89KB and 170.08KB is made of:

- the `ember-engines` modules:

```
;define("ember-engines/-private/engine-ext")
;define("ember-engines/-private/engine-instance-ext")
;define("ember-engines/-private/route-ext")
;define("ember-engines/-private/router-ext")
;define("ember-engines/components/link-to-component")
;define("ember-engines/components/link-to-external-component")
;define("ember-engines/engine")
;define("ember-engines/initializers/engines")
;define("ember-engines/routes")
```

- the `my-engine` modules:

```
;define("my-engine/config/environment")
;define("my-engine/engine")
;define("my-engine/resolver")
;define("my-engine/routes")
;define("my-engine/templates/application")
```

And finally the `ember-concurrency` modules aliased to be available inside the `my-engine` resolver:

```
;define.alias("ember-concurrency/helpers/cancel-all", "my-engine/helpers/cancel-all");
;define.alias("ember-concurrency/helpers/perform", "my-engine/helpers/perform");
;define.alias("ember-concurrency/helpers/task", "my-engine/helpers/task");
;define.alias("ember-concurrency/initializers/ember-concurrency", "my-engine/initializers/ember-concurrency");
```

YMMV depending on what addon you use though, but you can use this demo app as a starting point to check whether some code is really duplicated or not.

Hope this helps

Comment: I edited my description above with example. Please check

Answer (score 0):

#### Update in answer to updated question 11/12/19

The short answer is you cannot make each of your dependencies only part of your app's package.json. What you have where you specify each dependency in each addon and app's package.json is correct.

Npm will only install one version of each package. It does some complicated 'magic' to resolve which dependency gets used. If you think about it, this is the only thing that could happen because JS and the browser can only have on version of each library available since things are made available globally on the window. Your app would have now way of telling the difference between version `x.x.x` of a library and `x.x.y` of the same library because that library is always exposed with the same name globally, e.g., `Ember`.

#### Original answer

We have had some success reducing packages installed by using lerna and a mono repo: https://github.com/lerna/lerna. Note however, we have not had any success using the lerna commands. Instead we simply run `npm i` in each addon/app. The order `npm i` is run is critical: you must start with the base of your tree first i.e., start with the addon that does not consume an of your other addons/apps and move your way up.

Our mono repo contains three ember applications and two addons:

```
addon-1
addon-2
  - consumes addon-1
app-1
  - consumes addon-1
app-2
  - consumes addon-1 and addon-2
app-3
  - consumes addon-1 and addon-2
```

In the structure above, `npm i` must be run in this order: `addon-1`, `addon-2` and `app-1`, `app-2` and `app-3`.

We have experimented with different ways of including the packages in package.json of each addon/app. It's come down to this, example for `app-2`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "addon-1": "file:../addon-1",
  "addon-2": "file:../addon-2",
},
```

`file:` allows you to reference a module in your mono repo using a relative path.

Comment: I edited my description above with example. Please check

Comment: Update the answer based on the update to your question.